# How can run sql query in textbox in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a textbox and i want to write the query in textbox and show the result in datagridview.

if i write something like this `Select * From Login` in textbox and click on button to show the result in datagridview.

i have tried this code but unable to do it.

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LAPTOP-A56NKPB9\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=DB_EMS;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("'" + query.Text + "'", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        dgv.DataSource = dt;
```

I know it's a bad idea but i need to complete this task.

Comment: What happens when you run this?

Comment: Also, I assume you're okay with users typing `DROP TABLE Login` in there?

Comment: Incorrect Systex near `Select * From Login`

Comment: if `query.Text` is already a string that represents the whole expression, why are you adding extra quotation marks?

Comment: Does it state where exactly does the syntax error occur? The problem seems to be with the format of your SQL command.

Comment: `query.Text` is a textbox value that's why i used quotation marks

Comment: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'select * From Login'.`

Comment: Try removing the single quotes as suggested.

Comment: @DanGuzman it's works now after removing single quotes.